# In angular 2 for library @angular/router. this.router.subscribe doesnt seem to exist anymore?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In angular 2 for library @angular/router. this.router.subscribe doesnt seem to exist anymore?

It used to work on the router-deprecated old version but now it doesnt seem to.
Does anyone know what its changed too?

**This is my current code**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf, NgClass} from '@angular/common';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'HeaderNavigation',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: 'header.html',
  directives: [NgIf, NgClass, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HeaderNavigation{
  router : Router;
  isContactUs: boolean = false;
  isBlog: boolean = false;
  isSignUp: boolean = false;
  isJobs: boolean = false;

  constructor(router: Router){   
      this.router = router;

      this.router.subscribe((currentRoute) => {
          this.isContactUs = false;
          this.isBlog = false;
          this.isSignUp = false;
          this.isJobs = false;

          if(currentRoute === "contact")
            this.isContactUs = true;

          if(currentRoute === "blog" || currentRoute.substring(0, 4) === "blog")
            this.isBlog = true;

          if(currentRoute === "login")
            this.isSignUp = true;

          if(currentRoute === "newJobs" || currentRoute.substring(0, 6) === "newJob")
            this.isJobs = true;
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is now

```
this.router.changes.subscribe(
```

and it doesn't provide any value (just `null`), it only notifies about route changes.

To get the current route inject `Location` and get the `path()` from there.

If you just start migrating to the new router, I suggest to stay with `router-deprecated`, it's likely the router will be replaced again.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this change this evening.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it changed to

> this.router.changes.subscribe(() => {
>
> })